# What are the different ways to restart/manage services in Docker Container within Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I understand the concepts of Docker but I'm relatively new to it. I am trying to figure out some best practices with Docker. I read that you're supposed to have a single service per container and manage that.

My question is what is(are) the actual way(s) to go about editing the configuration of a service and then restarting it?

I've seen this being done with 'service restart' or 'systemctl' but some containers do not support this ('service command not found' for example in Alpine). It didn't make sense to install initscripts (I honestly don't even know how to do it in the case of Alpine for example).

Use Case:
I recently created a Dockerfile for JBoss7 which extends an image. Since I did not start the service in my Dockerfile, I'm assuming it was started in the base image. Do I refer to the base image Dockerfile to check how to restart the service (say after editing some configs in my Dockerfile)?

This is a general question about how services are created and managed as opposed to the use case I've give here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, a Docker container runs a single process and then exits.  For many purposes it's equivalent to think about managing the container the same way you'd manage a process.  So for example, without Docker, when you change the config file, you don't "enter the process" with a debugger and run manual commands to restart it; you stop the process and launch a new one.  In the same way, with Docker, you stop the container and launch a new one.

That is: Docker containers don't usually have "services" *per se*, and you almost never thing about "managing services" or "restarting processes" inside a container.  Just delete the whole thing.

Let's take an Nginx HTTP server as an example.  This has a text-format configuration file in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  Rather than trying to edit the file in a running container and try to restart the service, you'd typically store the configuration file outside the container, inject it using a Docker bind mount, and recreate the container once you change it.

```bash
$EDITOR nginx.conf           # edit the config file on the host
docker run -d -p 8080:80 \
  --name http
  -v "$PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" \  # and inject it
  nginx

# ...that configuration wasn't right...
$EDITOR nginx.conf
docker stop http
docker rm http
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name http \
  -v "$PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" nginx
```

You can use a tool like Docker Compose to hold the `docker run` arguments in a YAML file so you don't have to repeat them over and over.

You might argue that the Nginx configuration in this context shouldn't be managed by the application operator.  It has things like HTTP path mappings that might be specific to a combined Docker container stack but there isn't anything there that would need to be changed by an end user.  In that case it could make sense to build your custom configuration into a derived image

```bash
FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# CMD et al. from base image are automatically reused
```

You'd iterate on building image and relaunching the container

```bash
$EDITOR nginx.conf
docker build -t myname/nginx .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name http myname/nginx

$EDITOR nginx.conf
docker build -t myname/nginx .
docker stop http
docker rm http
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name http myname/nginx
```

Almost every mainstream Docker image works this way.  It's possible to run multiple things in a container using init systems like supervisord or heavy-weight OS-management tools like systemd, but these are usually frowned upon.  I'd guess your JBoss image launches a Tomcat server or something similar as the only process in its container, and you need to delete and restart it.

Also note this sequence never runs `docker exec` or `docker cp`, and beyond details in the Dockerfile or the location of the bind-mounted config file, it never really worries about what's "inside" an image.  I don't have to worry about losing an edit to a file inside a container, or my container behaving differently because the application restarted vs. being launched in a clean environment.  There are some unusual cases where these are needed (actual debugging, getting an initial copy of a config file) but these tools aren't usually part of your day-to-day flow.